# Webpack externals in both node and the browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

I have an isomorphic React application which runs in both the browser and on the server. I build the same code for both by running two separate Webpack builds through two different entry points and with different configs.

The problem is that the external file that exists on the browser window via an external script tag (Google Maps in this instance) obviously won't exist when running in node on the server. The code is identical except the entry point file.

index.html:

```
// index.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX"></script>
```

Simplified config:

```
// Server Webpack config
{
    entry: 'server.js',
    target: 'node',
    externals: {
         google: google
    }
}

// Client Webpack config
{
    entry: 'client.js',
    target: 'browser',
    externals: {
         google: google
    }
}
```

The Component:

```
// The view which builds and runs fine in 
// the client but doesn't run on the server.
var React = require('react'),
    css = require('./style.css'),
    google = require('google'); // Nope, not on the server obviously!

var Component = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                // Do maps stuff
            </div>
        );
    }

});
module.exports = Component;
```

My question is how should I handle this?

```
Error: Cannot find module 'google'
```

I currently have a solution which I'm not at all keen on.

```
// Server Webpack config
{
    entry: 'server.js',
    target: 'node',
    externals: {
         google: google
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'ENV.browser': false }),
    ]
}

// Client Webpack config
{
    entry: 'client.js',
    target: 'browser',
    externals: {
         google: google
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'ENV.browser': true }),
    ]
}

// The component
var React = require('react'),
    css = require('./style.css');

if (ENV.browser) {
    var google = require('google');
}

var Component = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                if (ENV.browser) {
                    // Do maps stuff
                }
            </div>
        );
    }

});
module.exports = Component;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` to replace the module with a noop, as per an idea from [Dustan Kasten](https://twitter.com/iamdustan/status/577561601353465856):

```
{
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^google$/, 'node-noop'),
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks handy! What about when I actually start accessing the properties on the external object? Would you simply check it exists before working with it?

Comment: That would work. `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` allows you to rewire your request to any module, so you could also create a simple mock of the module and use that on the server. If you only refer to the `google` variable in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, it doesn't matter, as it will never be fired when using `React.renderToString`.

Comment: I was thinking of stubbing it but that's a great point about `componentDidMount`. This is the reassurance I was looking for. Thank you!